# VBA pops up with warning sign in messagebox but no error message

Tags: excel, vba, warnings

I am trying to open all files in a specified folder one by one, set calculation to automatic to extract data from our reporting system (IBM Cognos/TM1), save the file, close it and continue with the next file.

My macro keeps bugging. There is no error description, just an empty box with a warning. I thought it may have been an issue with speed as the Citrix is somewhat slow. I have added doevents, breaks etc. to make sure that the files are fully calculated and saved. It usually happens after saving or before opening the next file. The files have a lot of of tabs and they take a while to calculate.

When I run the macro stepwise,it works like a charm.

I hope that one of you geniuses can help me solve this.

Thanks for your time anyway.

Below is my code:

```
Sub RefreshAllFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim filePath, month, year, fileName, fileType As String
Dim a, b As Date
Dim folder As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Clear the list of processed files
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F6:F" & LastRow + 1).Clear

'Retrieve Target Folder Path from the sheet
filePath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(9, 2) & "\"

'Filters Excel files
fileType = "*.xls*"

'Obtain the filename of the excel file in the folder
fileName = Dir(filePath & fileType)

'Obtain the parameters
month = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, 2)
year = "Year " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 2)

i = 4

a = Now()

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While fileName <> "" 
    'Disable popups
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Check if file is open already. It will be read-only
        If IsFileOpen(filePath & fileName) = True Then
              MsgBox fileName & " is already open. Please close the file and re-run the macro!"
              Exit Sub
        End If

    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=filePath & fileName)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code.
    DoEvents

    'Write the filename in the statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Updating file " & fileName

   'When workbook is opened paste the parameters in the file
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cockpit").Cells(11, 3) = month
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cockpit").Cells(15, 3) = month
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cockpit").Cells(2, 4) = year

    'Set calculation to automatic and force Excel to finish calculations before continuing
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        'If calculation goes wrong, exit the sub and reset application settings. Loop until calculation is finished
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            n = 0
            Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
           DoEvents
            n = n + 1
        Loop

    'If the user is not connected to TM1 the field Project will be empty after calculation. Then exit the macro
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cockpit").Cells(4, 3) = "" Then
        MsgBox "You are not connected to TM1. Please connect and restart the macro!"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.StatusBar = "Ready"
            Application.StatusBar = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

      'Add the filename to the list of completed files
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i + 2, 6) = fileName
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i + 2, 6).Select
                With Selection.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                     Selection.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                     Selection.Interior.Color = 6299648
                     Selection.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
                End With

      i = i + 1

    'Save and Close Workbook disable popup alerts (will choose the default button)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Set calculation to manual before saving the file
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False

    'Save the file and wait for 1 min before continuing to ensure saving is completed
        wb.Save
         Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:02:00"))

    'Close the file and wait for 30 secs before continuing to ensure file is closed
        wb.Close
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
        Set wb = Nothing
        DoEvents
    'If a error message shows up after the file has been saved, continue to the next file
    On Error Resume Next

    'Get next file name and loop to the next file
      fileName = Dir

  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
b = Now()

  MsgBox "UPDATE COMPLETE! It took " & Format(b - a, "hh:mm:ss")

  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Ready"
    Application.StatusBar = False
MsgBox "There was an error in " & fileName & ". Please re-run the macro for this and the remaining files!"
End Sub
```

[image: Error pop-up]

Comment: you want to try to create a [mcve] to receive better help. one thing i see is that maybe replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `wb` since you do declare the variable. And move this With block ...`With Selection.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1` to work directly on the range without selecting.

Comment: A is implicitly  declared as a variant not a date. If you hav'nt already done so, install Rubber duck and look at the code inspection report.

Comment: @freeflow - same for `Dim filePath, month, year, fileName, fileType As String` everything except `fileType` is a variant. That will slow speed down for sure.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem. It still pops up with no error message. I do not have the rights to to install software on my pc unfortunately. Do you know of any online alternatives?